# Can't find error PHP

Tags: php, email

So, this is my first attempt in PHP so it might be very easy to fix. I am trying to make a form which can be submitted and sent to administration's e-mail.

I am running a server with MAMP, going online filling the form, submitting it and I get error:

```
We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.

Please go back and fix these errors.
```

Full PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "I HAVE CORRECT EMAIL HERE 4 SURE";
    $email_subject = "eShop Contact Form";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['fname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['lname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['fname']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['lname']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    //$country = $_POST['country']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['subject']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
//    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>

    <!-- include your own success html here -->

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

    <?php

}
?>
```

This is the part that should be having problem:

```
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['fname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['lname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }
```

P.S I have copied the code from http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php here and edited it a little.

Comment: Yes, you _edited it a little_.  You changed `first_name` to `fname` etc. in the code, did you change it on the form???

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and it will tell you.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have my own form and that's why I changed those variables and the names are correctly corresponding I can assure you that

Comment: And your form `method="post"`?

Comment: <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">      @AbraCadaver Yeah

Comment: @AbraCadaver Those two lines of code didn't show anything new

Comment: @GiorgiQutateladze [I'm posting this here because I originally posted it on an answer that is likely to be deleted:] If what you just posted in the comments below is the output of `var_dump($_POST)`, then your problem is obvious: your are using field names like `firstname` and `lastname`, but your PHP expects `fname` and `lname`.

Comment: Also, it's a *really bad* idea to copy and reuse code you don't understand but found on the internet. Even if the code you copy isn't malicious (but how would you know?) it may have security vulnerabilities or other major problems. And, in fact, the code above does have vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I will start from here.
I will re-edit your code

**SUBMIT.PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['formid'])) {
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "yourmail.com.id@maisetting.com";
$email_subject = "eShop Contact Form";
//
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comments = $_POST['comm'];
// I was replace this line
// validation expected data exists
if(empty($fname) or empty($lname) or empty($mail) or empty($subject) or empty($comments)){
$err_msg = 'We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.';
} else {
// check mail registered
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$mail)) {
$err_msg = 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
} else {
// check name
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$fname)) {
$err_msg = 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
} else {
// check Last name
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$lname)) {
$err_msg = 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
} else {
// Check comment
if($comments<2 or $comments=='') {
$err_msg = 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
} else {
// SEND msg from the visitor
$err_msg = 'Your Messages Was Send. ThankYou!';
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($fname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
//    $email_message .= "Country: ".clean_string($country)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

}}}}} } else { $err_msg = 'Add Your comment here'; }
?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php require('SUBMIT.PHP'); ?>
<form action="#" method="post" />
<p><label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="First name here" name="fname" />
</p>
<p><label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last name here" name="lname" />
</p>
<p><label>Mail</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Add yourmail here" name="mail" />
</p>
<p><label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Subject here" name="subject" />
</p>
<p><label>Your Comment</label>
<textarea name="comm"></textarea>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="formid" value="Send"  /></p>
</form>
<?php echo $err_msg; ?>
```

Now, do and test.